# Microsoft BotFramework v4 Task schedule and States

Tags: c#, azure, task, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'am using the botframework v4 from Microsoft to build a bot. I have implemented a Task with a delay to check if the user has not answered the last 2 hours. If the 2 hours timeout is reached, the function will do some action and reset the conversation state. This works fine but there are 2 issues:

1. I can not cancel this task if the user has already resetted the conversation manually over the dialogs.
2. The states in the Delay Task are not updated. As example, if the user adds a note to a list, the State inside the delay task is 0 at the end of the conversation.

My delay task code:

```
 EndConversation = Task.Delay(600000).ContinueWith(async (t) =>
            {
                bool wordGenerated = false;
                xyzState = await GetXYZState(dialogContext);

                if (xyzState.ListCount > 0)
                {
                    //retry 4 times sending the word document
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        if (await GenerateWordDocument.CreateDoc(dc, _xyzAccessor, _xyzAccessor2))
                        {
                            wordGenerated = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start by pointing out that starting long lived `Task`s inside of a bot is not going to be a very scalable solution. Like web applications, bots tend to be scaled out across multiple servers and also have to be tolerant to process or server restarts. You will likely want to use some kind of external, distributed timer system that will ensure that, regardless of your bot's lifetime, the timer will be persisted and eventually invoked. Aside from that, it's also not a great use of machine resources. If your bot has 100s or, hopefully 1000s of users and you're constantly creating `Task`s with `Task::Delay` you are going to be encurring quite a bit of overhead in terms of resources. Normally a solution like this would be to have a store of timers that is being serviced by a single worker.

Ok, that warning aside, let's just talk about the specific problems you're facing:

> 1. I can not cancel this task if the user has already resetted the conversation manually over the dialogs.

Well, you could... you would just have to create a companion `CancellationTokenSource`, pass it's `Token` to the `Task.Delay` and the `ContinueWith` and then, if you want to cancel it, call its `Cancel` method which will release the delay timer and ensure it's never invoked.

I don't know what `EndConversation` is exactly in your sample code, but instead of just being a `Task` it would now need to be a data structure that had the `Task` and `CancellationToken` on it. A simple tuple could work here, otherwise create yourself a new class.

> 2. The states in the Delay Task are not updated. As example, if the user adds a note to a list, the State inside the delay task is 0 at the end of the conversation.

Yeah, so you're seeing stale state because you're closing over the original `dialogContext` variable with your continuation. You are technically not supposed to use something like `DialogContext` or `ITurnContext` beyond the current turn.

What you're trying to do here is something called proactive messaging. Even if your logic doesn't actually message the user back, the same concept would apply. So what you'd want to do is actually capture the `ConversationReference` outside the closure for your continuation and then use that `ConversationReference` inside the closure to continue the conversation later. That would look a little something like this:

```
// Capture the conversation reference from the current turn's activity
var currentConversationReference = dialogContext.Context.Activity.GetConversationReference();

// Capture the adapter of the current turn (this is fugly, but kind of the best way to do it right now)
var botAdapter = dialogContext.Context.Adapter;

// Kick off your timer with the continuation closing over these variables for later use
Task.Delay(600000).ContinueWith(async (t) =>
{
    await botAdapter.ContinueConversationAsync(
        YourBotsApplicationId, 
        currentConversationReference, 
        (proactiveTurnContext, ct) => {
            // Now you can load state from the proactive turn context which will be linked to the conversation reference provided
            var xyzState = await GetXYZState(proactiveTurnContext);

            // Example of sending a message through the proactive turn context
            await proactiveTurnContext.SendActivityAsync("Hi, I just did a thing because I didn't hear from you for two hours.");
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, I want to send a proactive message and send a word document when the user has not interacted with the bot for 6 hours. The conversation should be resettet. Do you have an idea what is the best way to implement the timer job? Maybe azure web jobs?

Comment: Too much for a comment, but there are _many_ options for scheduling a timeout callback. Depends on what techs you're familiar with, how much code you want to write. One of the simplest solutions: schedule a message in the future on an Azure Storage Queue, set up an Azure Function to be triggered by that queue and then the function triggers an event in the bot via DirectLine. Code free option: define a Logic App instance w/an HTTP trigger, then a Delay action followed by an HTTP action that again triggers the bot via DirectLine. Could be done w/Durable Functions too. All support cancellation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have changed the implementation to your suggestion with the queue.
1. The Bot will now push a item to a Azure Queue with an invisible message time of X hours.
2.The Azure Function which is triggerd by the queue will send a message to the directline adapter of the bot with the original conversation details.
3.The bot will reply to the old conversation.

Thank you for your help! 
If I find Time I will write a blog post for it...

Comment: @theface, did you managed to write any post about the solution or github repo, I would be glad to know how you implemented the solution. I have to implement something similiar.